# How to sort specific string, in the following situation (PYTHON)

Tags: python, logic, acronym

I was trying to build a Acronym Shortner (as a beginners project)
LINK:http://pastebin.com/395ig9eC

Explaination:

**++ACRONYM BLOCK++**

If the user the string variable is set to something like "international Business machines" it return IBM

but in the...

```
++SORTING BLOCK++
```

If the user the string variable is set to something like 
"light amplification by the simulated emission of radiation"

i tried to split the whole sentence by:

```
 z=string.split(" ")
 l=len(z)
```

then use this following loop:
   
**'''|SORING BLOCK|'''**<

```
for x in range(0,l,1):
    esc=z[x]
    if (z[x]=="by" or z[x]=="the" or z[x]=="of"):
            esc=z[x+1]


    emp=emp+" "+esc


print emp
```

But the PROBLEM is the that when there are 2 consecutive exclusion words python messes it up.
How do i solve it?

Comment: *"python messes it up"* - no, it does exactly what it was asked to, you messed up! Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This takes the first letter of each word in the sentence, it ignores words that are excluded, and then puts the letters together using join.

```
#Python3
def make_acronym(sentence):
    excluded_words = ['by', 'the', 'of']
    acronym = ''.join(word[0] for word in sentence.split(' ') if word not in excluded_words)
    return acronym.upper()
```

Example:

```
>>> make_acronym('light amplification by the simulated emission of radiation')
'LASER'
```